# validateJarFile not loaded in both eclipse and netbeans

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

While running project in Tomcat Server i am receiving following message

```
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Programming\Internproject\HRDBMS\HRDB\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Can anyone help me to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat, according to the servlet specification, will not allow a web application to supply its own copy of any servlet API classes. So, Tomcat is refusing to load that JAR file.

Your webapp should work correctly, assuming that you aren't trying to use features not supported by your version of Tomcat (which you didn't bother to mention). Tomcat 6.0 and later support servlet 2.5 (and earlier), and Tomcat 7.0 supports version servlet 3.0 (and earlier).

Comment: In tomcat6 as well i received same message.I guess do to above problem my application is not able to load some of css.I am very new to jsp servlet and tomcat, could you please guide me how to get out of this problem.

Comment: i recently downloaded servlet 3.0 and included in lib by adding external jar, still i am receiving same things

Comment: Stop trying to put servlet.jar into your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory: it is illegal to do so under any revision of the spec, under any version of any servlet container. Take it out and that warning will disappear. Your webapp should work properly (well, as properly as it's likely to) whether you get this error or not.

Comment: Yes Christopher Schultz now i am not receiving that message but now i am getting following message.

Comment: I understand: read the (entirely clear) documentation or hire someone if you are too lazy to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

remove servlet.jar.Tomcat has its own servlet.

Comment: Yes i removed servlet as per you said, now i am not receiving that same message but now i am receiving following message.

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found

Comment: The APR issue is different. Read the Tomcat documentation for the APRLifecycleListener to figure out what that means. Note that it is an INFO message and represents no error at all. Also note that it has been in your log files the whole time: you just missed it because of all the other junk that's been spewing into your log file for other reasons.